# Dash drop down menu graph

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm attempting to implement a live-update graph that is only displayed if the user selected it from the drop down menu. I've made a callback with input from "intervals" and from the dropdown menu "oxygen". I thought if "value" is "0" then no chart has been selected and I could return "null"(???), and if 'value' = '1', then the graph would update. Is this possible? or is my approach incorrect?

```py
dcc.Graph(id='live-graph2', animate=False),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='graph-update',
            interval=10000,
            n_intervals=0
        )),
        dbc.Col(html.Div([
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='oxygen',
            options=[{'label': s, 'value': s}
                     for s in main_graph.keys()],
            value=[],
            multi=True),
```

```py
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('live-graph2', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('oxygen', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals')],
)
def update_graph_scatter_2(n,value):
    if value == 0:
        ....
    else:
        data = {}
```

Comment: Can you give an update? Did you take a look at my answer below, or are you still experiencing problems?

Comment: Thank you. Indeed your answer was the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach the problem differently.

If you don't want to display the graph at all when no dropdown option is selected then the `Graph` component doesn't need to be in the layout by default.

Instead you could create a container component that your `Graph` component is appended to dynamically based on the option values of your `Dropdown` component.

Below is a simplified example using sample data, adjust per your requirements:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import plotly.express as px
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

df = px.data.iris()

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Interval(id="graph-update", interval=10000, n_intervals=0),
        html.Div(id="graph-container"),
        dbc.Col(
            html.Div(
                [
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id="oxygen",
                        options=[{"label": s, "value": s} for s in [1, 2, 3]],
                        value=[],
                        multi=True,
                    )
                ]
            )
        ),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output("graph-container", "children"),
    [
        dash.dependencies.Input("oxygen", "value"),
        dash.dependencies.Input("graph-update", "n_intervals"),
    ],
)
def update_graph_scatter_2(value, n):
    if value:
        # Change the line below to dynamically create the figure based on value
        fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length")
        return dcc.Graph(id="live-graph2", figure=fig)

    return html.Div()
```